# Add Columns to Custom DGV User Control through Designer

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, user-controls

I am creating a custom user control which simply holds a DataGridView.  This DataGridView has custom functionality of events which will be used in 3-4 different forms.

Ideally what I'd like to be able to do is drop my CustomDGV in a form using the designer and add columns through the designer via right click -> Edit Columns as you would for a regular DGV.  However, this option is not available using my CustomDGV.  I can add columns programmatically, but I like keeping things visual where possible.

My guess at the reason for this is that the DGV is private inside of my CustomDGV hence the reason the edit columns option does not show.  Is there a way to make is protected/public without going into the .designer.cs file?  This is only a hunch and may be way off.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose these properties to the designer  in your custom user control using [Design Time Attributes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx)